# Stack snippets: are there any official guides on this function?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

I've seen some users using snippets but I'm not sure how to do it myself. Might sound trivial but I'd like to know.

Using JSFiddle or CodePen to show working code doesn't seem as effective as using inline live code right here on SO so that users never have to go off site but I couldn't find any official posts on how to use the SO UI and or snippets.

**Questions:** I've just found out that snippets are limited to HTML, CSS & JS.
If posting JS that uses a library like jQuery, can I make that live as well or is it just native JS?
Will there be any future consideration for PHP?

I searched for similar questions but there's nothing that answers all my questions.

Thanks.

Comment: *Will there be any future consideration for PHP?* Very unlikely, that requires backend processing

Comment: @CertainPerformance that helps a lot! When asking about PHP I didn't mean any MYSQL functions. I've looked online for PHP testers for live code there are a couple and they're abysmal. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) may enable C# ([Blazor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazor)) and even [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) in the future.